# Code runs but does not send an sms

Tags: java, android

I am trying to send an SMS. The code runs but does not send any SMS. There are no bugs. Please guide what must have gone wrong.

```
package com.example.smsbomber;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendSMS();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendSMS() {
        String phoneNumber = "00923002228885";
        String message = "Hello World!";

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure u have added `SEND_SMS` Permission in AndroidManifest?

Comment: I have it on the manifest

Comment: Huh.! @FahadUddin make sure your phone have enough credit to send an sms ;)

Comment: @QadirHussain: Haha. Yes I am sure it has that too.

Answer (score 0):

check your Number once. I think you should try to remove "00" at starting position from your phone no. use try-catch() to escape from the error.Just use only "923002228885" or if you still not getting msg then remove "92" also like "3002228885".

I have tried this before 3 days ago and it's working fine for me.but yes make note it, I am not getting success to send message more than 160 char but in less than 160 char it works fine.

```
try {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(sender_PhoneNo),null, your_sms, null, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SMS faild, please try again later!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am using this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/) as reference.

Hope it will help you.